System Error and no dashboard on install
Finally got a new install of Civi on what is a just installed Drupal 10 site.
When I got to Civicrm, I get a system error with this informations:
System Status: Error
Public Assets Not Published
Organization Setup
Configure Default Mailbox
Smarty Update (v2 => v4)
When I lick the link below to "Manage and see Details" it just says System Error with no Civi dashboard, just the default page from my website (which I have never had appear on a Civi install before).
I did look at the logs and got this:

2024-05-14 14:50:27-0700  [error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "DB Error: constraint violation"
"code" => null
"exception" => Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException {#2267
#message: "DB Error: constraint violation"
#code: 0
#file: "/home/vsource4/www/www/edboost.org/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Error.php"
#line: 974
#cause: DB_Error {#2263
+error_message_prefix: ""
+mode: 16
+level: 1024
+code: -3
+message: "DB Error: constraint violation"
+userinfo: "INSERT INTO civicrm_dashboard_contact (dashboard_id , contact_id , column_no , is_active ) VALUES ( 1 ,  2 ,  1 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (vsource4_edboost2024_civicrm.civicrm_dashboard_contact, CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_dashboard_contact_contact_id FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES civicrm_contact (id) ON DELETE CASCAD)]"
+backtrace: array:46 [
0 => array:6 [
"file" => "/home/vsource4/www/www/edboost.org/vendor/pear/db/DB.php"
"line" => 986
"function" => "__construct"
"class" => "PEAR_Error"
"type" => "->"
"args" => array:5 [
0 => "DB Error: constraint violation"
1 => -3
2 => 16
3 => array:2 [
0 => "CRM_Core_Error"
1 => "exceptionHandler"
]
4 => "INSERT INTO civicrm_dashboard_contact (dashboard_id , contact_id , column_no , is_active ) VALUES ( 1 ,  2 ,  1 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (vsource4_edboost2024_civicrm.civicrm_dashboard_contact, CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_dashboard_contact_contact_id FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES civicrm_contact (id) ON DELETE CASCAD)]"
]
]
1 => array:7 [
"file" => "/home/vsource4/www/www/edboost.org/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php"
"line" => 575
"function" => "__construct"
"class" => "DB_Error"
"object" => DB_Error {#2263}
"type" => "->"
"args" => array:4 [
0 => -3
1 => 16
2 => array:2 [
0 => "CRM_Core_Error"
1 => "exceptionHandler"
]
3 => "INSERT INTO civicrm_dashboard_contact (dashboard_id , contact_id , column_no , is_active ) VALUES ( 1 ,  2 ,  1 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (vsource4_edboost2024_civicrm.civicrm_dashboard_contact, CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_dashboard_contact_contact_id FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES civicrm_contact (id) ON DELETE CASCAD)]"
]
]
2 => array:6 [
"file" => "/home/vsource4/www/www/edboost.org/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php"
"line" => 223
"function" => "_raiseError"
"class" => "PEAR"
"type" => "::"
"args" => array:8 [
0 => DB_mysqli {#283
+_debug: false
+_default_error_mode: null
+_default_error_options: null
+_default_error_handler: ""
+_error_class: "DB_Error"
+_expected_errors: []
+fetchmode: 1
+fetchmode_object_class: "stdClass"
+was_connected: null
+last_query: "INSERT INTO civicrm_dashboard_contact (dashboard_id , contact_id , column_no , is_active ) VALUES ( 1 ,  2 ,  1 ,  1 ) "
+options: array:8 [
"result_buffering" => 500
"persistent" => false
"ssl" => false
"debug" => 0
"seqname_format" => "%s_seq"
"autofree" => false
"portability" => 0
"optimize" => "performance"
]
Someone with a similar problem on a Word Press site seems to have solved the problem by logging out and logging back in, but I tried that and also made a new admin Drupal user but same result.

Any thoughts?  It took me a few tries to get this installed due to some other issues.  Do I uninstall and try again?
** Update - I did a full uninstall including deleting the database.  Did a reinstall on a fresh DB from the command line and I've checked the civicrm.settings.php to make sure all the paths are correct.  Same issue.
Thanks for any help!
-tiffani

Final update, after installing and uninstalling Drupal/Civicrm multiple times, I think the root of all of my problems (which were semi-solved to various degrees by various fixes, but never completely solved) was having my web root at the wrong level.
Unlike how I had Drupal 7 installed, I needed to have my domain point to [mydomain]/web and then install at www/www/[mydomain].  Prior to that I had my domain pointing at www/www, so the site was located at www/www/[mydomain]/web but the URL was rendering as www.[domain.org]/[domain.org]/web.
I was using various htaccess redirects to get this setup to function, but then the site kept getting tripped up -- and Civi, in particular, was unhappy.
In the answer to another question @demerit pointed out that my install seemed to be at the wrong level, so I did a final reset and although everything is not working perfectly, things are working now.
Hope this may help someone else!

After you installed Civi can you logout and login back into Civi?

I don't think I'm ever logging into Civi.  When I click the Civi link, I just get the front page content from Drupal and this note:
"Access Keys:
System Status   Powered by CiviCRM 5.73.1, free and open source AGPLv3 software."
I don't see anything that looks like a Civicrm  dashboard.

Yeah, I meant logout and login back


Not really an answer but an update.  Did a full uninstall and reinstall.  According to my Drupal status page all systems are go.
However, I still get this screen when I got to the Civi home screen.  When I click the Status link, the page is almost identical.
It doesn't look like Civi nor is there any way for me to log in or try to set anything up.
Am I missing something obvious here?
Thank you!
-tiffani
